can anyone help me with this question?
During exercise, a capillary of radius =500m
and length =0.1cm.
L=0.1 cm supplies oxygen to surrounding muscle tissue. Blood flows through the capillary with a volumetric flow rate =1L/s. The partial pressure of oxygen in the blood entering the capillary is 2,=100mmHg, and oxygen diffuses from the capillary into the tissue. The diffusion coefficient of oxygen in blood is =2×10^−5cm^2/s, and the oxygen solubility in blood is =0.003mL O2/mL blood/mmHg. The muscle tissue consumes oxygen at a rate of =0.1 mol/m^3/s.
İ FOUND THİS The calculated oxygen transport rate is approximately 1.884×10^−4 mLO2/s, which indicates the amount of oxygen diffusing out of the capillary into the tissue per second.

Welcome Yagmur. Please be aware of our homework policy. You will need to show what you've tried and where you got stuck else risk closure and deletion of your question - oh, and you would need to ask an actual question.

That's a slight improvement, but ideally you'd need to add a source or description of how you calculated it. - You've still not asked a question.
